# Need to show database records before and after changes have been made in SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, record

Im executing a query in SQL-server that does the following using 2 tables: table 1 called "accadj" has a list of old and new values for 3 fields, therefore accadj has 6 columns. Table 2 called "accnt" has the actuals records in it. when a record in accnt matches the old vales in accadj, the values in accnt are changed to to match the new values in accadj. accadj looks like this:

[image: accadj looks like this]

and accnt looks like this:
[image]

the pictures are both just snippets of the full tables. the code for the query that im describing works and looks like this:

```
Update accnt
set accnt.accno = accadj.accnonew,
    accnt.jno =accadj.jnonew,
    accnt.saccno =accadj.saccnonew
from accnt accnt join accadj accadj with(nolock)
on accnt.accno  = accadj.accnoold
   and accnt.jno  = accadj.jnoold
   and accnt.saccno =accadj.saccnoold
```

I need to show what the records looked like before AND after the query has been run and then print out that list. i know how to show the records before the query has been run using this code infront of the code i just described:

```
select accnt.*
from accnt, accadj
where accnt.accno  = accadj.accnoold
and accnt.jno  = accadj.jnoold
and accnt.saccno =accadj.saccnoold
```

but after the query has been run, the old records no longer exist, and i cant figure out how to display the newly changed records with the old versions of themselves. any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: You will have to run a query BEFORE your update to get the values before the update. Stick those values in a temp table and then execute your update. BTW, why are you using NOLOCK here? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? This is not a magic go fast option. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: i dont know what it does, but someone showed me how to make that program, is there a better way? im not ok with missing rows.

Comment: Then remove the NOLOCK hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT Clause on your update statement
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Your inserted table is your new values and deleted is your old values.
You can insert these into a temp table/table variable and then user further in your code.  Or if your version of SQL supports look at change data capture.

Comment: i am not using mssql. how do i use change data capture?

Comment: Sorry, your tags show you using SQL-Server, which engine are you using?  that will change the options available to you.

Comment: AnySQL Looks to be a management utility that serves as an interface.  The underlying Engine will change the options, ie MSSQL, MYSQL, ORACLE, POSTGRESQL

Comment: You can enable all of this via script without SSMS, though please consult with your database administrators before attempting any of this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369(v=sql.100).aspx